# How I can localized error messages for Spring Validation errors, like @PathVariable @Min(1), @Email etc, if I use @ControllerAdvice?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security, localization

For example:

```
@GetMapping("/exception/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getException(@PathVariable @Min(1) Integer id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(id.toString());
}
```

it must returns "must be greater than or equal to 1" (default message) when I call this function with id=-5 from the eng page. And something like this "doit être supérieur ou égal à 1", when i coll it from french page.

Answer (score 0):

hibernate-validator jar file contains different localization messages. You need to configure based on `Accept-Language` header in the request it will decide which message to be displayed.

```
@Bean
public AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    final AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver resolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return resolver;
}
```

The Response DTO object.

```
@Data
public class ErrorDto {

    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String error;

    public ErrorDto(HttpStatus status, String error) {
        timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.status = status;
        this.error = error;
    }

}
```

Then in ControllerAdvice catch ConstraintViolationException and show a response.

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler({ConstraintViolationException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    String error = "";
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
        error = violation.getMessage();
    }
    ErrorDto errorDto = new ErrorDto(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, error);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDto, errorDto.getStatus());
}
```

It will give you response for given controller.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-23T21:08:07.0459025",
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "error": "doit être supérieur ou égal à 1"
}
```